# jQuery POST not sending Content-Type on IE10

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-10, content-type

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and Internet Explorer Version 10.0.9200.16686, Update Version 10.0.9 (KB2870699), on Windows 7 64-bit.

When using $.ajax to POST, the Content-Type header is not being sent. It works fine in Chrome and other browsers, and I believe used to work fine before on IE10 so I suspect some update to IE10 caused an issue.

I can also manually create an XMLHttpRequest and send a request, so I'm assuming it must be a bug in jQuery that's the real issue? I tried upgrading to 1.10.2, but get the same problem.

I have the contentType set using `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    processdata: true,
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

I've also tried explicitly setting it as part of the `$.ajax` options.

```
var options = {
    url: basePath + 'login',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        UserName: username,
        Password: password,
        RememberMe: rememberMe || false
    })
};
return $.ajax(options).then(...);
```

Any ideas how to fix it will be appreciated.

Note: we were initially using CORS, hence the reason for the `xhrFields` and `crossDomain` settings, but are currently hosting everything on the same domain because of issues with IE8 and IE9 and `XDomainRequest`.

Comment: I've tested it with exact same setup (OS/Browser/jQuery), and it works just fine for me. Can you provide a self-contained working example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ndm found the issue, was caused by another script :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that we still had the [xdr.js](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js) script included to enable CORS on IE, which was causing this issue.