# IE click event troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I have such page

[http://автопортал-юга.рф/organizations/all_organizations/1](http://%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/organizations/all_organizations/1)

and in all browser's all is ok, when i click on link "подробнее" - i see ajax data appended to page view... But why IE (in my case 10,11,12) - didn't do anything?

main thing - no error log's or warnings, and i'm confused (  what i do wrong?

ie debugger throw on this js part:

```
return typeof jQuery !== strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                undefined;
```

also i use rails 4 and it's turbolinks.

How to solve this issue?

or just how to catch what is bad?

html part:

`<a href="/organizations/9" data-remote="true">подробнее...</a>`

**everybody who minus - first explain why! There is reall issue!**

Comment: everybody who minus - first explain why! There is reall issue!

Comment: this is valid question should not be down voted.
If you down vote then please explain.
I am upvoting because i think it's important and interesting question.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here, but for your question of "how to catch what is bad"  Have you tried Fiddler yet?    http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: My guess for the downvotes is due to a lack of information, plus a page that is in a non-English character set, which makes our browsers whine when we try to open it. Can you provide a simplified example case where your problem occurs?

Comment: @blakeo_x how this page work's on you machine? just find there blue link "подробнее" and that's all...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 it works fine in Chrome, but IE8 throws an error and won't take me to where the error occurred. It's a lot of work to go digging for the script in your otherwise complex page. It'd be easier for us to help if you provided a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) case displaying the problem without all of the fluff.

Comment: @blakeo_x i will try, just how to do? if this return's ajax data

Comment: @blakeo_x also what error ie throw?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 It throws a generic syntax error. Also, it doesn't have to do any AJAX calls. You already know the error occurs with that `return ...` line you gave. Find out what values are going into it (the values of the vars _strundefined_, _e_, _eventHandle.elem_, and _arguments_)...or even better, **dont** make a test case. Instead, break that complex return statement down into separate if statements in your original code and try to debug it then.

Comment: @blakeo_x this is from jquery lib i believe http://jsfiddle.net/GxF5u/

Comment: @blakeo_x it's all js code from my app, which is generated with assets pipeline from rails, and i didn't have such part in my app, so this is jquery

Comment: @blakeo_x did you see fiddle?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 yes, it doesn't reproduce your issue. This appears to be your first time using JSFiddle, and teaching you how to correctly use it is beyond the scope of this comments section. I suggest you break the complex return statement down into separate `if ()` statements in your original code and try debugging from there.

Comment: @blakeo_x in all browser's all is ok, even i have only jquery lib without any code - same issue, so it's jquery something, but what ?

Comment: @blakeo_x main trouble is that i didn't see any error

Comment: Perhaps this previous Question can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158164/jquery-post-not-sending-content-type-on-ie10

Comment: Is this question still valid? I just went to the site provided and tried it in IE 11 (10 and 9 via document mode) and links are working correctly and do not throw any exceptions, content is loaded fine on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your error isn't coming from a development gem's incompatibility with IE?

Recently I was getting JS errors from various plugins and extra functionality, e.g. miniprofiler/jquery incompatibility in Chrome. IIRC the error was similar to the one you describe.

Also FWIW to help with IE specific incompatibilities perhaps Modernizr will help

https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the data you're returning is JSON.

Is it possible you already tested this with empty data the first time?

IE caches the request unless you specifically set headers on the servers not to cache it. In fact, if you're using CORS, IE will cache the preflight request's response too - meaning it won't even attempt to make a request to the server, and will just return a 304.

Open an http-analyzer such as fiddler or charles, and check what happens with the request. Is it sent? What's the response code (200 / 304)? Does it contain the data you expect in the response, or some older data? You should also be able to see this in the IE network tab as well.

Comment: my question was deleted... but there i write: lol, but all was when i have comments in js (